# TCP clients that have same MAC address in TCP server application

Tags: c#, networking, tcpclient, mac-address

I have a TCP server app that is written in C#. I accept TCP clients that comes from 1234th port of my server IP address. I do not know MAC addresses of TCP clients. There is no problem up to now, server runs perfectly but i realized that when TCP clients with same MAC addresses connects to the server, i could not handle their connections. What is the problem in that sitation? How can i learn the MAC address of TCP client that attempts to connect to my server? IF i can learn that, i would not accept TCP client that has the same MAC address in the connected clients' list.

Comment: You will only see MAC address as far as your local segment. Imagine MAC addresses flooding the internet...

Comment: I could not understand your comment.

Comment: The MAC address is probably your router. It's just an address of the latest hop (machine) that forwarded the packet to you.

Comment: How does the "could not handle their connections" manifest itself? You should not need to worry about mac addresses at TCP level.

Comment: What do you mean by "I could not handle their connections"? Can you give more details about the problem symptoms you're seeing? I suspect it doesn't have anything to do with MAC.

Comment: I could not send data by using TcpClient.Client.Send(data) method

Comment: Please post the error you get.

Comment: I understood the problem. There is a task that pings every client periodically. I searched internet and learned that clients that have the same MAC on a same network is an unwanted situation. So my app tries to ping the client and disconnects it because it could not receive a ping reply.

Comment: ping in general in unreliable for checking whether clients are down. If you do receive an answer, great, the client is up, but not receiving an answer does not mean anything because firewalls frequently drop ICMP packets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem for the netadmin, not the guy who writes the server. Two identical MAC addresses in a LAN is a procurement error, or a netadmin error if dynamically allocated. Don't write code to fix problems that shouldn't arise. You would have trouble sending ordinary responses to such clients, let alone pinging them.